# WooCommerce Как сохранить Предложенную цену товару?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть задача для товаров сделать возможность предлагать пользователю свою цену.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, как забирать и где правильнее всего будет хранить это значение для текущего пользователя?

Вот в файле теми `/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php`

Если пользователь ввел значение в `input`, то оно должно сохраниться для дальнейшей передачи в Заказ(Order).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его в `post_meta` положить? Как связывает Submit с получением значения с этого поля?
Пробовал так

```
 <!-- Custom propose price -->
        <label class="propose_price">
            <span class="propose_price__desc"><?php _e("You can propose a price") ?></span>
            <input class="propose_price__val" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'propose_price', true) ?>" name="propose_price" type="number">
        </label>
        <?php add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', function ($product){
            $woocommerce_number_field = $_POST['propose_price'];
            if ( ! empty( $woocommerce_number_field ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'propose_price', esc_attr( $woocommerce_number_field ) );
            }
        }, 10 ); ?>
```

но до корзины ничего не доходит.
Так же Пробовал привязаться к хуку корзины, но тоже что-то значение не заносит...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woo_propose_price',  20);
function woo_propose_price($product_id){

    add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', function ($cart_item_data, $product_id) {
        $cart_item_data['propose_price'] = get_post_meta($product_id, 'propose_price', true);
        return $cart_item_data;
    }, 10, 2);

    echo '<label class="propose_price">
            <span class="propose_price__desc">'. _e("You can propose a price") .'</span>
            <input class="propose_price__val" value="'.  get_post_meta($product_id, 'propose_price', true) .'" name="propose_price" type="number">
        </label>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предоставленный вами код не является полным и, похоже, содержит некоторые ошибки. Чтобы добавить введенную пользователем пользовательскую цену в корзину и сохранить ее в заказе, вы можете сделать следующее:

1. Добавьте настраиваемое поле ввода, чтобы пользователь мог ввести предложенную цену в файл шаблона:

   ```html
       <label class="propose_price">
           <span class="propose_price__desc"><?php _e("You can propose a price") ?></span>
           <input class="propose_price__val" value="" name="propose_price" type="number">
       </label>
   ```
2. В файле functions.php используйте фильтр woocommerce_add_cart_item_data, чтобы добавить введенную пользователем пользовательскую цену к данным товара в корзине:

   ```
    add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', function ($cart_item_data, $product_id) {
        if (isset($_POST['propose_price'])) {
            $cart_item_data['propose_price'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['propose_price']);
        }
        return $cart_item_data;
   ```
3. Используйте фильтр woocommerce_get_item_data, чтобы отобразить пользовательскую цену в корзине и при оформлении заказа:

   ```
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', function ($item_data, $cart_item) {
        if (isset($cart_item['propose_price'])) {
            $item_data[] = array(
                'name' => __('Proposed Price', 'woocommerce'),
                'value' => wc_price($cart_item['propose_price']),
            );
        }
        return $item_data;
    }, 10, 2);
    }, 10, 2);
   ```
4. Используйте действие woocommerce_add_order_item_meta, чтобы добавить пользовательскую цену в метаданные заказа:

   ```
   add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', function ($item_id, $cart_item) {
        if (isset($cart_item['propose_price'])) {
            wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Proposed Price', wc_price($cart_item['propose_price']));
        }
    }, 10, 2);
   ```

Это позволит пользователю ввести свою собственную цену, добавить ее в корзину, отобразить в корзине и при оформлении заказа и сохранить в заказе для дальнейшего использования.

Comment: Перепроверил код, он не рабочий.  Вставляю в функцию `add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data',  `  добавил   `echo '<pre>';
    print_r ($cart_item_data);
    echo '</pre>';` оно ничего не заносит в корзину. Можете пожалуйста, перепроверить ваш код ?

Comment: Добрый вечер, я перепроверил, у меня проблем нет. У меня, к сожалению нет предположений, почему у вас он не работает, надеюсь у вас получится узнать решение.